# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Datas> to Cursor

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and learning to connect sqllite database to an app. This is the main activity and getting an error in Cursor cursor = (Cursor) db.getAllData(); line. Error says Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Cursor. please can somebody help me overcome this.

public Cursor getAllData () {

```
    List<Datas> dataList = new ArrayList<Datas>();

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Datas r = new Datas();
            r.setkonsumen(cursor.getString(1));
            r.setbarang(cursor.getString(2));
            r.setharga(cursor.getString(3));
            r.setqty(cursor.getString(4));
            // Adding contact to list
            dataList.add(r);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return transaction list
    return dataList; // error here

}
```

and here is Datas class :

```
public class Datas {

//private variables
int _id;
String _konsumen;
String _barang;
String _qty;
String _harga;

// Empty constructor
public Datas(){

}
// constructor
public Datas(int id, String konsumen, String barang, String qty, String harga){
    this._id = id;
    this._konsumen = konsumen;
    this._barang = barang;
    this._qty = qty;
    this._harga = harga;
}

// constructor
public Datas(String konsumen, String barang, String qty, String harga){
    this._konsumen = konsumen;
    this._barang = barang;
    this._qty = qty;
    this._harga = harga;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getkonsumen(){
    return this._konsumen;
}

// setting name
public void setkonsumen(String konsumen){
    this._konsumen = konsumen;
}

// getting phone number
public String getbarang(){
    return this._barang;
}

// setting phone number
public void setbarang(String barang){
    this._barang = barang;
}

// getting phone number
public String getqty(){
    return this._qty;
}

// setting phone number
public void setqty(String qty){
    this._qty = qty;
}

// getting phone number
public String getharga(){
    return this._harga;
}

// setting phone number
public void setharga(String harga){
    this._harga = harga;
}
```

}

Comment: Ignore this comment.  I see now it was a formatting issue.

Comment: emm.. where i have to write that line ?? thanks :D

Comment: Also make sure to close the cursor. And have a look at the if-do-while statement - a simple while-loop would do the same. And have a look at java code conventions: you should definitely use camelcase for your getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
 public Cursor getAllData () { // return type is cursor
```

But you return

```
 return dataList; // which is List<Datas> dataList
```

Change to

```
 public List<Datas> getAllData () {
```

Comment: if i change it into List, i got an error in these line : customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData()); // error here, because it needs cursor
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

Comment: Here :
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                
                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData()); // error here
                
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });

Comment: The constructor CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity, List<Datas>) is undefined

Comment: @AcilAz Change the constructor also as required. the second param in the constructor must be of type `List<Datas>`